# Angular 4 passing data to html

Tags: angular

main.component.html

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
    height:
    <input type="number" name="height" [(ngModel)]="user.height">
    <br><br>
    Weight:
    <input type="number" name="weight"[(ngModel)]="user.weight">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<h5 *ngFor="let user of users">

    {{user.score}}

</h5>
```

main.component.ts

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
    users = [];

    user = {
        height: 0,
        weight: 0,
    };

    onSubmit() {
        console.log(this.user.height);
        console.log(this.user.weight);

        var score = this.user.weight * this.user.height;
        this.users.push(score);

        console.log(score);


        this.user = {
            height: 0,
            weight: 0
        }
    }
}
```

this.user.weight and this.user.height are multiplied and saved in var score. But how  do I pass the var score to show in my main.component.html? I tried to push score in users array but its not showing up in my main.component.html.

Comment: you don't have a member `score` in `user`. add it and store the calculated value to it.

Comment: You're using TypeScript, but you'rte not using types anywhere. Specify the types of your variables, and the compiler will tell you what you're doing wrong. `users` is supposed (I guess) to be an array of users (so `Array<User>`), but you're pushing scores to this array (of type number). You're supposed to display the score of each user, but you don't have any score in the users. Also, your code is not indented, making it very hard to read. This is all basic stuff. Learn and apply the basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't push it into users; remove `var` and use `this.score = this.user.weight * this.user.height`, and then in Your main...html you can use as `{{score}}`

Answer (score 1):

score is not a object , it should be

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users">
<h1>{{user }}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `user` is an object. `users` is an array. Don't miss the `s`

Comment: @i-- no: Read the code: it populates the array using `var score = this.user.weight * this.user.height;
this.users.push(score);`. So the elemtns of the array are numbers.

Comment: @i-- actually score

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<h5 *ngFor="let user of users">
{{user | json}}
</h5>
```